# Session storage data lost while pushing to next page in react and

Tags: reactjs

I have used state and access local storage data, and when I click on Edit button it is pushed to the next page.
When I come back to this page again I am losing the session storage data.

```
   const [userRights, setUserRights] = useState 
    (JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('userRights')));
    enter code here`{  (Edit || userType === 2) &&
    <Link to=""  onClick={editPropertyHandler.bind(this,field.propertyId)}
    key='Edit'> 
    <Icon  name='edit' color='red' />
   <span>  Edit </span>
   </Link>
  }
```

```
const editPropertyHandler = (propId) =>{  
 axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_API_URL}Organization/GetPropertyDetails`,
         { params: {
         'PropertyId': propId
         },  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${ctx.APIToken}`}},  
         )
        .then((response)=>{
           // console.log(response.data);
             const data = response.data.response;
             data.organizationDetails = {}; 
             
     data.organizationDetails.organizationName=orgData.organizationDetails.organizationName;
             data.organizationDetails.organizationId=orgData.organizationDetails.organizationId;
             localStorage.setItem('editProperty',JSON.stringify(data));
             history.push('/NewProperty');
        })   
        
       }
```

Comment: In your code, you are setting a local storage value, and getting a different session storage value from a different key. Can you make sure your question contains all the required code to reproduce this issue? (Currently the set value is never read, and the read value is never set)

Comment: that is a different value set. My problem is when im leaving this page and coming back the userRights are lost. Even I tried putting the userRights in context using useContext then also Iam losing the data. while clicking on Edit button.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed it by removing history.push and worked with Link with params.
I was losing the session storage while history push was used.

I removed -    history.push('/NewProperty');
And used Link to ="/NewProperty",
It worked fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).